# Is there a way to check for duplicate folder/file names without causing a race condition?

Tags: c++, filesystems

So in my treeView_AfterLabelEdit, I would like to apply the user inputted folder name, and see if the file-system returns an error for a duplicate name. Is there an elegant way to do this using a try-catch block?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What has a "try-catch block" to do with "without causing a race condition"? What  is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Are you trying to create a file, and don't want to overwrite an existing one?

Comment: @KerrekSB Let's say for example I am using a shared folder. If I use a loop to traverse through the nodes and check their names to look for a duplicate before creating a new one, I will be considering the state of the file-system at a given instance of time. That will lead to a race condition. One way to solve it would be to try to apply what the user has inputted, and return an error if a duplicate folder is found.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Let's say I have a folder named ABC. If I create another folder with the same name, it gets created. When I do a refresh it goes away.. What I would like to do is notify the user about a duplicate folder name AFTER the program is done trying to create that folder ( "after" to prevent race conditions. Kindly read my comment for KerrekSB for explanation).

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm assuming from your treeView_AfterLabelEdit that you are using .Net and VC++.

I don't know off the top of my head of a way that you can do this with exception handling, but here are some other ideas:

You could use `Directory::CreateDirectory`. This will create the directory, and if it already exists, it won't do anything.

`Directory::Exists` will let you check whether the directory exists before you do things with it.

I'm not sure what any of this has to do with a race condition though.

Comment: Let's say for example I am using a shared folder. If I perform a check before creating a tree node, it will consider the file-system only at that given instance of time. This will lead to a race condition if there are multiple users or processes trying to create a folder.

One way to resolve this would be to try to create the folder, and return an exception if a duplicate is found (or anything else goes wrong).

Comment: Ah, I see now, thank you. What code exactly are you using to create the directory?

Answer (score 0):

Right, so this is clearly a [TOCTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) problem - which means that the only reasonably safe solution is to "try to create it, and complain if that doesn't work." - doing anything else will just make the code more complicated and you STILL have to check if there was an error when the code tries to create it.

Comment: Exactly! I have the "create it" part, but I can't find the right solution to the "complain if that doesn't work" part.

Comment: Looks to me that there is a pretty decent example here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterlabeledit.aspx

It uses MessageBox to inform the user about "you've done something wrong".

Comment: That example deals with invalid characters (which have nothing to do with a possible race condition). I have searched around, and still haven't found anything. The problem would have been solved if an exception was thrown by the file-system if a duplicate was found.

Comment: Yes, of course. Replace the "check if the string contains invalid characters" with a "create the directory" call, and then check if that succeeds or not. Or am I missing something very obvious about .Net here?

Comment: The call succeeds no matter if there is already a folder with the same name. I get a duplicate folder in the list view, which goes away after a refresh.

Comment: Well, then you are clearly not adding the directory on the actual filesystem, since you can't have two directories with the same name in any filesystem I'm aware of (except perhaps VAX/VMS, but they would be copies of the same directory with different version numbers, which I don't think is what you were looking for). Or you are not signaling back that "I don't want to continue this" correctly.